# Creating a emission plane and hiding it in Blender 2.81

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, emission

How do I create emission material and then hide the plane that emits the light in Blender 2.81?

Comment: Are you trying to get the same effect as an *Area Light?* You can press Shift+A, *Light* > *Area* to add one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Light Path* node to make the material appearance different from its influence.

From *Add > Input > Light Path* use the *Is Camera* socket to mix between your *Emission Shader* and a *Transparent Shader*.

[image]